# How to Use a Setter Function to Check Whether a Function Parameter has Changed - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, tkinter, parameter-passing

Here is my code:

```
def DisplayFiles(which):
    contentLabel = tk.Label(window, text = '\n'.join(files[indexlist[which]][1:]))
    contentLabel.place(x = 150, y = 80)
```

I am using Tkinter and am trying to display files with the above function when a button is pressed. The variable "which" is the string name of a button. "indexlist" is a dictionary holding indexes for button names (I dynamically created them). My problem is trying to display files for two different buttons. When I click one button, the function above displays the files. But when I click another button, the label displays over the previous one. I am working on a destroy() method, but I need to know how to check when the parameter "which" is changed. Help would be appreciated!

Also, the values of indexlist, and files are not the problem. I just want to find a way to check when the function parameter is changed. Thanks!

Comment: Please give a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't make a new Label every time, just update the old Label.

```
# make an empty Label
contentLabel = tk.Label(window)
contentLabel.place(x = 150, y = 80)

def DisplayFiles(which):
    # update the Label contents
    contentLabel.config(text = '\n'.join(files[indexlist[which]][1:]))
```

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!